# SQL recursive CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I have a column where I need to keep finding the last record value associated with the original record in that column.

```
select rec1, val1 from table1:

rec1   val1    
a1    t1      
t1    t2    
t2    null

a2    t7

t7    null
```

There are essentially 2 original records in this table (a1, a2). I need to associate t2 with a1 in my sql query since the link is based on val1 column (a1 -> t1 -> t2) until val1 is null. The record a2 is linked to t7 only since there is no further linkage for t7 (a2 -> t7).

I hope there is a 'simple' way to accomplish this. I have tried but am unable to make much progress.
Thanks

Comment: This isn't solved with a cursor. Instead you need a Recursive CTE.

Comment: yup, yup. and the title needs to be edited as well.

Comment: I changed the title. Could you please post a sample query?

Comment: Did you try googling `Recursive CTE`?  Stack Overflow isn't a free code-writing service

Comment: `WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
    VALUES (1)
  UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 100
)
SELECT sum(n) FROM t;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive CTE formulation.  This version assumes no loops and that you don't have more than 100 links in the chain:

```
with cte as (
      select rec1, val1, 1 as lev
      from table1 t1
      where not exists (select 1 from table1 tt1 where tt1.val1 = t1.rec1)
      union all
      select cte.rec1, t.val1, cte.lev + 1 as lev
      from cte join
           table1 t1
           on t1.val1 = cte.rec1
    )
select *
from (select cte.*, max(lev) over (partition by rec1) as maxlev
      from cte
     ) cte
where maxlev = lev;
```